# java -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy is not effective

Tags: java, jvm

I want to modify the maximum heap size through *jinfo*.

```
jinfo -flag MaxHeapSize=3122032640 <pid>
```

Since `AdaptiveSizePolicy` is enabled by default, modifying flags directly will result in an exception. So I disabled AdaptiveSizePolicy when the process started.

```
java -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy Sleep.java
```

I can also get the right result through jinfo

```
jinfo -flag UseAdaptiveSizePolicy 18220

-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
```

But when I modify the maximum heap memory through jinfo again, exceptions will still occur.

```
jinfo -flag MaxHeapSize=3122032640 18220

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.attach.AttachOperationFailedException: flag 'MaxHeapSize' cannot be changed
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineImpl.execute(VirtualMachineImpl.java:224)
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.executeCommand(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:309)
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.setFlag(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:282)
    at jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jinfo.JInfo.flag(JInfo.java:146)
    at jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jinfo.JInfo.main(JInfo.java:127)
```

It seems that `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` is not effective.

Does anyone know the reason?

> I know the `-Xmx` flag to set the maximum heap size.

JDK: openjdk 13.0.1

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

VM flags:
-XX:CICompilerCount=3 -XX:ConcGCThreads=1 -XX:G1ConcRefinementThreads=4 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=1048576 -XX:GCDrainStackTargetSize=64 -XX:InitialHeapSize=134217728 -XX:MarkStackSize=4194304 -XX:MaxHeapSize=536870912 -XX:MaxNewSize=321912832 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=1048576 -XX:MinHeapSize=134217728 -XX:NonNMethodCodeHeapSize=5830732 -XX:NonProfiledCodeHeapSize=122913754 -XX:ProfiledCodeHeapSize=122913754 -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=251658240 -XX:+SegmentedCodeCache -XX:SoftMaxHeapSize=536870912 -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseFastUnorderedTimeStamps -XX:+UseG1GC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to modify the maximum heap size through jinfo.

It is not possible. `MaxHeapSize` is not manageable flag, it cannot be changed in runtime.

`-XX:UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` flag is completely different thing. If configures whether GC may resize heap generations basing on the GC statistics, in order to achieve pause/throughput/footprint goals.